# Asus ROG Zephyrus Pop-OS freezing no wifi

Tags: nvidia, reboot, freeze, pop-os, asus

I recently acquired an Asus ROG Zephyrus G15, with Nvidia RTX 3060 graphics card, and I have been trying to get it fully functional with Linux. So far I have tried Mint, Fedora and Pop-OS. Pop-OS has delivered the best performance out-of-the-box so far. After installation, everything works. Until it doesn't.

I am running Linux pop-os 6.2.6-76060206-generic #202303130630~1683753207~22.04~77c1465 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed M x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. With nvidia drivers and asusctl installed.

I am able to use my computer normally until randomly, as far as I can tell, it freezes and I need to hard reboot. It froze while watching youtube videos, it froze while editing spreadsheets, it froze on lockscreen. Sometimes minutes after initial boot, sometimes I go the whole day without an issue.

Display remains on, but mouse and keyboard completely unresponsive. On rebooting sometimes I get no wi-fi and need to reboot again. I setup ssh server, but was not able to connect to debug.

I did monitored tests for hardware with Psensor for overheating or spikes during these episodes but I couldn't see any abnormality.

I saw some issues on github of users with similar experiences, but most were polluted by several problems on the same thread without any having my specific combination of events.

this is ths output to syslog around the latest event, at 5:58 today:

```
May 11 05:52:55 pop-os wireplumber[2528]: BlueZ Battery Provider is not available, won't retry to register it. Make sure you are running BlueZ 5.56+ with experimental features to use Battery Provider.
May 11 05:52:55 pop-os wireplumber[2528]: RFCOMM receive command but modem not available: AT+CSRSF=0,0,0,1,0,1,3#015
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os bluetoothd[1100]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_04_FE_A1_5C_EC_0C/sep1/fd1: fd(32) ready
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os kernel: [  249.954389] input: EDIFIER W806BT (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input42
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2649]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device EDIFIER W806BT (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event20)
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2649]: (**) EDIFIER W806BT (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2649]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'EDIFIER W806BT (AVRCP)'
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2649]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event20 13:84 fd 95 paused 0
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2649]: (**) EDIFIER W806BT (AVRCP): always reports core events
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2649]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event20"
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2649]: (II) event20 - EDIFIER W806BT (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2649]: (II) event20 - EDIFIER W806BT (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2649]: (II) event20 - EDIFIER W806BT (AVRCP): device removed
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2649]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input42/event20"
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2649]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "EDIFIER W806BT (AVRCP)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 21)
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2649]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2649]: (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2649]: (II) event20 - EDIFIER W806BT (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
May 11 05:52:57 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2649]: (II) event20 - EDIFIER W806BT (AVRCP): device is a keyboard

May 11 05:59:39 pop-os systemd-modules-load[738]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
May 11 05:59:39 pop-os systemd-modules-load[738]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
May 11 05:59:39 pop-os systemd-modules-load[738]: Module 'ecryptfs' is built in
May 11 05:59:39 pop-os systemd-modules-load[738]: Inserted module 'msr'
May 11 05:59:39 pop-os systemd-modules-load[738]: Inserted module 'kyber_iosched'
May 11 05:59:39 pop-os lvm[719]:   1 logical volume(s) in volume group "data" monitored
May 11 05:59:39 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
May 11 05:59:39 pop-os systemd[1]: Finished Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
May 11 05:59:39 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files...
May 11 05:59:39 pop-os systemd-sysctl[755]: Couldn't write '1' to 'kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone', ignoring: No such file or directory
May 11 05:59:39 pop-os systemd[1]: Finished Coldplug All udev Devices.
May 11 05:59:39 pop-os kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 6.2.6-76060206-generic (jenkins@warp.pop-os.org) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #202303130630~1683753207~22.04~77c1465 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed M
```

there is nothing particular about the lines before or after, nothing that I have seen particularly on any other episode, except the gap between 5:52 and 5:59
I had a terminal running `tail -f /var/log/syslog` at the time, and I could see at least 2 lines of the log that aren't available after reboot. the lines I saw at the time were not errors though

I appreciate any help trying to solve this as this is basically making my machine unusable as its unpredictable when its going to happen.

Comment: Before anything else update UEFI as well as SSD/NVMe firmware, if available. Also make sure the Nvidia drivers are properly installed and running (you need to manually sign them or disable Secure Boot in UEFI, preferably the former but you can do the latter for troubleshooting purposes).

Comment: Nvidia drivers come pre installed and enabled with pop-OS. OS recognizes them and applies them correctly. How does the UEFI update relates to this problem though? Problem occurs with OS booted and working normally